# PHP SOAP Server Returns XML With No Tags

Tags: php, xml, soap, server, tags

I have the following php server code:

```
$xml ="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
$root = "Data";
$warmdata = "WarmData";
$brinedata = "BrineData";
$permindata = "PerMinData";
$xml .= "<$root>";
    $xml .= "<$warmdata>";
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $xml .= "<WarmIn>";
            $xml .= $row['value'] . " " . $row['time'];
            $xml .= "</WarmIn>";
        }

        foreach($result2 as $row)
        {
            $xml .= "<WarmOut>";
            $xml .= $row['value'] . " " . $row['time'];
            $xml .= "</WarmOut>";
        }
    $xml .= "</$warmdata>";

    $xml .= "<$brinedata>";
        foreach($result3 as $row)
        {
            $xml .= "<BrineIn>";
            $xml .= $row['value'] . " " . $row['time'];
            $xml .= "</BrineIn>";
        }

        foreach($result4 as $row)
        {
            $xml .= "<BrineOut>";
            $xml .= $row['value'] . " " . $row['time'];
            $xml .= "</BrineOut>";
        }
    $xml .= "</$brinedata>";

    $xml .= "<$permindata>";
        foreach($result5 as $row)
        {
            $xml .= "<WarmPerMin>";
            $xml .= $row['value'] . " " . $row['time'];
            $xml .= "</WarmPerMin>";
        }

        foreach($result6 as $row)
        {
            $xml .= "<BrinePerMin>";
            $xml .= $row['value'] . " " . $row['time'];
            $xml .= "</BrinePerMin>";
        }
    $xml .= "</$permindata>";
$xml .= "</$root>";

header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
return $xml;

$options=array('uri'=>'http://localhost/');
$server = new SoapServer(NULL,$options);
$server->setClass('DBData');
$server->handle();
```

I am trying to get a properly formatted xml output using the soap client, but when I request the xml, the out only contains the numbers retrieved from a database in a single row, without the actual xml tags. 
How could I modify it so I will have the tags in the output?

Comment: Is this a function? If not the return will terminate execution

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, it is a function. It works, only the output is missing all xml tags, and displayed in a single line instead.

Comment: Well then SHOW ALL THE RELEVANT CODE. We can only debug what we see, **we are not clairvoyant**

Comment: It is the whole code, just the function name is missing from the beginning, and the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Those tags are not allowed. You have to write them:

```
< replace with &gt;
> replace with &lt;
```

Comment: Now this really is just a comment. Please dont comment in an answer, it is likely to get downvotes and you dont want that

Comment: How do you mean? He asks why the tags are not shown and I'm responding with how he should put them in his code.

Comment: @WesleyDeKeirsmaeker Where do I have to put these?

Comment: I have edited my aswer. You have to replace < and > chars.

Comment: @WesleyDeKeirsmaeker It worked, thank you, but still the whole xml is displayed in a single line. Is there a solution for that?